# MySQL - Renaming database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Using PHPMyAdmin version 4.5.2 and SQL 5.7.9.
I have a database called 'name' with 3 tables 'one' 'three' 'two' in that specific order, ascending.
Now when I use the Operations>Rename Database feature in PHPMyAdmin and set the new name to 'newname' it renames just fine.
I look into the console to see what command it used to do that:

```
            RENAME TABLE `name`.`two`
              TO `newname`.`two`;
            DROP DATABASE `name`;
```

What I need is someone to explain these commands, how did it do that? I only see it mentioning the table 'two' and yet it properly manages to copy all of them (one, three, two)
I'd like to know because this being just a simple example, I will need to use these commands (Without using operations>rename database) in a more complex database filled will different all kinds of tables.

EDIT:

```
   RENAME TABLE `newname`.`two`
                TO `name`.`two`;
                   RENAME TABLE `newname`.`one`
                TO `name`.`one`;
                   RENAME TABLE `newname`.`three`
                TO `name`.`three`;
            DROP DATABASE `newname`;
```

Produces error:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\newname\two' to '.\name\two' (errno: 168 - Unknown (generic) error from engine)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the console did not log all commands because `rename table` command in the form you specified moves only one table from the source db to the target. Try issuing the 2 commands manually yourself and you will see what I mean.

You can use [rename table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) to rename multiple tables and move them to a different db by providing a list of tables to rename:

```
RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name
    [, tbl_name2 TO new_tbl_name2] ...
```

Comment: I seem to be misunderstanding this completely. So what am I supposed to write, overall. To achieve the stated task? I tried something like "               RENAME TABLE `newname`.`two`
                TO `name`.`two`;
                   RENAME TABLE `newname`.`one`
                TO `name`.`one`;
                   RENAME TABLE `newname`.`three`
                TO `name`.`three`;
            DROP DATABASE `newname`;" I simply receive errors. I will paste the above as a code snippet to be more readable in my initial post.

Comment: I know that it is my fault, but I'm not a mind reader! What errors do you get?

Comment: "#1025 - Error on rename of '.\newname\two' to '.\name\two' (errno: 168 - Unknown (generic) error from engine)"

Comment: I'd also like to add that this was me trying to convert the name from 'newname' to 'name' this time. Not the other way around like I mentioned I did initially.

Comment: The generic error bit suggest that the error was returned from operating system level. You need to get more details because this is specific to your environment. Show errors, show innodb errors, review mysql error log, etc.

Comment: The commands you are trying are completely fine as mysql is concerned.

Comment: You have to create the new database, before everything.  You can't rename a table to be in a database that doesn't yet exist.